# Library for polynomial calculus in Java?

Tags: java, math, interpolation, polynomial-math, calculus

Are there any (preferably open source) library for Java that allows one to do calculus with polynomial e.g. addition, multiplying, dividing by constans etc. ?

Also if it would be capable to interpolate several 2D points in a polynomial with Lagrange polynomial interpolation, it will be a plus.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the [Apache Commons Mathematics Library](http://commons.apache.org/math/index.html).

Polynomials are handled with [PolynomialFunction](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/polynomials/PolynomialFunction.html) and you can do a Lagrange interpolation with [PolynomialFunctionLagrangeForm](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/polynomials/PolynomialFunctionLagrangeForm.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following library could be of interest, if one would be interested in a more CAS like approach to polynomials in Java:

**Java Algebra System (JAS) Project**
http://krum.rz.uni-mannheim.de/jas/